# What fraction of the CPU time is wasted ? (Modern Operating Systems, 4th ed)

Tags: operating-system

it's my first post here.
I'm currently learning Modern Operating Systems and I'm stuck at this question : A computer system has enough room to hold five programs in its main memory. These programs are idle waiting for I/O half  of the time. What fraction of the CPU time is wasted?
The answer is 1/32, but why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer is 1/32, but why ?

The sentence "*These programs are idle waiting for I/O half of the time*" is ambiguous. Let's look at a few different ways of interpreting this sentence and see if they match the expected answer:

a) "Each of the 5 programs spends 50% of the total time waiting for IO". In this case, while one program is waiting for IO the CPU could be being used by other programs; and all programs combined could use 100% of CPU time with no time wasted. In fact, you'd be able to use 100% of CPU time with only 2 programs (the 1st program uses the CPU while the 2nd program waits for IO, then the 2nd program uses the CPU while the 1st task waits for IO, then ...). This can't be the intended meaning of "*These programs are idle waiting for I/O half of the time*" because the answer (possibly zero CPU time wasted) doesn't match the expected answer.

b) "All of the programs are idle waiting for I/O at the same time, for half the time". This can't be the intended meaning of the question because the answer would obviously be "50% of CPU time is wasted" and doesn't match the expected answer.

c) "Each program spends half of the time available to it waiting for IO". In this case, the first program has 100% of CPU time available to it but spends 50% of the time using the CPU and waits for IO for the other 50% of the time, leaving 50% of CPU time available for the next program; then the 2nd program uses 50% of the remaining CPU time (25% of total time) using the CPU and 50% of the remaining CPU time (25% of total time) waiting for IO, leaving 25% of CPU time available for the next program; then the third program uses 50% of the remaining CPU time (12.5% of total time) using the CPU and 50% of the remaining CPU time (12.5% of total time) waiting for IO, leaving 12.5% of CPU time available to the next programs, then...

In this case, the remaining time is halved by each program, so you get a "negative power of 2" sequence (1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, **1/32**) that arrives at an answer that matches the expected answer.

Because we get the right answer for this interpretation, we can assume that this is what "*These programs are idle waiting for I/O half of the time*" was supposed to mean.